# how to extract data with multiple filtering or searching and get multiple line use bash script

Tags: shell, awk, grep, cut

I have file log format like this

**Input**

```
2021-02-21 12:12:32 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2001K

Operation: ProcessOpenTablet

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_OpenTablet

Payload: {"id":"POS026","staff_id":"2","table_no":"2001K","customer_first_name":null}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-21 12:12:32 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2001K

Operation: GetListDishFormPOST

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_GetDishesList

Payload: {"id":"POS026"}

Response: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
2021-02-21 12:12:40 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2001K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS026","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 12:18:17 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: ProcessOpenTablet

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_OpenTablet

Payload: {"id":"POS027","staff_id":"2","table_no":"2001K","customer_first_name":null}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 12:18:18 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: GetListDishFormPOST

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_GetDishesList

Payload: {"id":"POS027"}

Response: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 12:18:28 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS027","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 15:18:28 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS028","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 12:24:04 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2003K

Operation: ProcessOpenTablet

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_OpenTablet

Payload: {"id":"POS028","staff_id":"2","table_no":"2001K","customer_first_name":null}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 12:24:04 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2003K

Operation: GetListDishFormPOST

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_GetDishesList

Payload: {"id":"POS026"}

Response: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to extract this data look output bellow and can dynamically search or filter, example filter the date "2021-02-22" Stored Procedure "sp_HDS_Payment", and the result will be

**Expected Output**

```
2021-02-22 12:18:28 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS027","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 15:18:28 Plugin: 

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS028","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I was tryin to use the grep or cat commands do that. but the data is only limited to 1 line, I want the data obtained example from "date" (2021-02-22) to "Response". How do I resolve this?

**NOTES :  filtering/searching must be match with two condition, in DATE input AND Stored Procedure = sp_HDS_Payment**

Comment: Are the blank lines part of the files?

Comment: I see 3 sections from the sample input that match on `2012-02-22` and `sp_HDS_Payment`, but only 2 of the sections is in the expected output ... did you leave out a filter? or should all 3 sections be in the expected output?  will you always have 2 filters to search for? what is the format of the filters and does each filter have to match a specifically labelled line (eg, only match `sp_HDS_Payment` if on the line with the label 'Stored Procedure')?

Comment: hi @markp-fuso so sorry, i just updated example data logs. please looks again in above :), thanks for correct me.

Comment: Hi @Cyrus yes, of course

Comment: @markp-fuso yes, filter must always match 2 conditions namely date and Stored Procedure = sp_HDS_Payment

Comment: You should read your file line by line and analyze each line individually combining them to sections, filtering, etc. Not applying a single grep command to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following awk solution:

```
 awk -v dat="2021-02-22" -v sp="sp_HDS_Payment" 'BEGIN { RS="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" } $0~dat && $0~sp { ORS=RS;print }' logfile
```

Set the record separator to dashes and then print the record only if it has the spcified date (dat) and stored procedure (sp)

The record separator determines how the file is going to be split into individual records.
$0 ~ .... then checks to see if the record ($0) contains the dat that is passed into awk with -v or the sp that is passed.

Comment: Hai @Raman Sailopal ,  Thanks it's work !!! but can you explain step by step in your code ? escpesially in part of BEGIN { RS="--------------------------" } $0~dat && $0~sp { ORS=RS;print }' ??

Comment: No worries, I've added some addional explanation

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `gnu-awk` with custom `RS`:

```sh
awk -v RS='-{5,}\n' -v dt='^2021-02-22 ' -v sp='sp_HDS_Payment' '{ORS=RT} $0 ~ dt && $0 ~ "\nStored Procedure: " sp "\n"' log.txt

2021-02-22 12:18:28 Plugin:

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS027","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 15:18:28 Plugin:

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS028","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 12:18:28 Plugin:

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS027","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-02-22 15:18:28 Plugin:

Table Number: 2002K

Operation: SettlePayment

Stored Procedure: sp_HDS_Payment

Payload: {"id":"POS028","operator_no":"2","table_no":"2001K"}

Response: [{"ErrCode":"01","ErrMsg":""}]

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Expanded form:

```sh
awk -v RS='-{5,}\n' -v dt='^2021-02-22 ' -v sp='sp_HDS_Payment' '
   {ORS=RT}
   $0 ~ dt && $0 ~ "\nStored Procedure: " sp "\n"
' log.txt
```